# How do I filter EF procedures by return type (e.g. via reflection or IL)?

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework, reflection, il

Let's assume that we already have the stored procedures mapped from a database via Entity Framework 6.0. I am trying to filter stored procedures by their return type and then use the return type to fill a grid via WPF.

Here is the query involved:

```
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("CT_EntityDataModel");
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
var myMethods = new ObservableCollection<MethodInfo>();
// The LINQ below can be offloaded to an ICommand for reflection using the Command pattern. If the Command pattern will be used much, it really should also be a Singleton.
var q = from t in asm.GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "CT_EntityDataModel"
        && t.Name.Equals("CRMEntities")
        select t.GetMethods();
```

When I use reflection to load the stored procedures, the information I want is in the [MethodInfoInstance].ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType. However, when I try to get more information on this UnderlyingSystemType, I get very little useful information. Here's the result of the immediate window:

```
j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType
{Name = "ObjectResult`1" FullName = "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[[CT_EntityDataModel.PROC_RE_ReadImportInvest_Result, CT_EntityDataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}
    [System.RuntimeType]: {Name = "ObjectResult`1" FullName = "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[[CT_EntityDataModel.PROC_RE_ReadImportInvest_Result, CT_EntityDataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}
    base: {Name = "ObjectResult`1" FullName = "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[[CT_EntityDataModel.PROC_RE_ReadImportInvest_Result, CT_EntityDataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}
    Assembly: {EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[[CT_EntityDataModel.PROC_RE_ReadImportInvest_Result, CT_EntityDataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    Attributes: Public | BeforeFieldInit
    BaseType: {Name = "ObjectResult" FullName = "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult"}
    ContainsGenericParameters: false
    DeclaringMethod: 'j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType.DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    DeclaringType: null
    FullName: "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[[CT_EntityDataModel.PROC_RE_ReadImportInvest_Result, CT_EntityDataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"
    GenericParameterAttributes: 'j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType.GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericParameterPosition: 'j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType.GenericParameterPosition' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericTypeArguments: {System.Type[1]}
    GUID: {3cea792c-523d-3659-8584-7b6e3ad1678b}
    HasElementType: false
    IsAbstract: false
    IsAnsiClass: true
    IsArray: false
    IsAutoClass: false
    IsAutoLayout: true
    IsByRef: false
    IsClass: true
    IsCOMObject: false
    IsConstructedGenericType: true
    IsContextful: false
    IsEnum: false
    IsExplicitLayout: false
    IsGenericParameter: false
    IsGenericType: true
    IsGenericTypeDefinition: false
    IsImport: false
    IsInterface: false
    IsLayoutSequential: false
    IsMarshalByRef: false
    IsNested: false
    IsNestedAssembly: false
    IsNestedFamANDAssem: false
    IsNestedFamily: false
    IsNestedFamORAssem: false
    IsNestedPrivate: false
    IsNestedPublic: false
    IsNotPublic: false
    IsPointer: false
    IsPrimitive: false
    IsPublic: true
    IsSealed: false
    IsSecurityCritical: true
    IsSecuritySafeCritical: false
    IsSecurityTransparent: false
    IsSerializable: false
    IsSpecialName: false
    IsUnicodeClass: false
    IsValueType: false
    IsVisible: true
    MemberType: TypeInfo
    Module: {EntityFramework.dll}
    Namespace: "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects"
    ReflectedType: null
    StructLayoutAttribute: {System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute}
    TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
    TypeInitializer: null
    UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "ObjectResult`1" FullName = "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[[CT_EntityDataModel.PROC_RE_ReadImportInvest_Result, CT_EntityDataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}
```

Is there a method on the UnderlyingSystemType or elsewhere that will allow me to get the return type?

And yes, I know the performance of reflection is horrible. Once I can figure out how to do this, I will optimize the code at the IL level. And if you tell me to use ADO.NET or something else, I will tell you that you have no idea what you are talking about. For your information, the only clean way that I would be able to get the return types directly from the database involves sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object, which is not included in databases prior to SQL Server 2012; moreover, dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object does not provide much useful information from procedures that contain dynamic SQL.

In the worst case, I suppose I could simply use a regular expression to grab the type from the MethodInfo instance .ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType.FullName, which looks like this:

> "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[[CT_EntityDataModel.PROC_RE_ReadImportInvest_Result,
>   CT_EntityDataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]"

If I look at the type PROC_CT_ReadImportInvest_Result, it's definition looks like this:

```
namespace CT_EntityDataModel
{
    using System;

    public partial class PROC_RE_ReadImportInvest_Result
    {
        public System.DateTime dtDate1 { get; set; }
        public string txtData1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want the "PROC_RE_ReadImportInvest_Result" part of the above FullName value. Is there a less ugly way to get this type instead of using a Regex to extract it?

Thanks,
Devin

***[Update (4/20/2014 at 5:56 PM PST): Here is the final code that solves this problem]:***

```
    // If these values will be consumed by a ViewModel, then we need to use an ObservableDictionary here.
public  Dictionary<MethodInfo, Type> GetTypesDictionary()
{
    // This is for our ViewModel.
    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("CT_EntityDataModel");
    Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
    // The LINQ below can be offloaded to an ICommand for reflection.
    var q = from t in asm.GetTypes()
            where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "CT_EntityDataModel"
            && t.Name.Equals("CRMEntities")
            select t.GetMethods();
    // We need to filter these to only those that return a dataset.
    // q can be offloaded to an IPredicateStrategy that returns only the results that match the strategy.
    return (from i in q
            from j in i
            where j.Name.StartsWith("PROC_") && j.Name.Contains("Global")
            let methodType = j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType
            where methodType.IsGenericType
            let test = j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType.GetGenericArguments()
            where test.Length > 0
            select j).ToDictionary(j => j, j => j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
// We can use a Strategy pattern to encapsulate the ".Name.StartsWith" logic.
// This would make an interesting extension method. 
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the underlying type that you are looking for is an anonymous type so that won't work. I think you should consider a different approach to your problem or else you will lose a lot of time.

Comment: @mostruash, although the mapping may be delegated, PROC_RE_ReadImportInvest_Result is not an anonymous type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are getting generic proxy object. You could try something like this:

```
var methodType = [MethodInfoInstance].ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType;

if(methodType.IsGenericType)
{
    methodType = methodType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```

PS. I am writing this from top of my head, so forgive me if there are some syntax errors.

Comment: j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType.GetGenericArguments() is throwing an IndexOutOfRangeException on some of the types. Any idea how to check if there are 0 results without throwing an exception?

Comment: Updated my answer. Of course, you might want to do some additional checks.

Comment: Here was the final code for that section:
`
var methodType = j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType;
       
       if(methodType.GetType() == typeof(ObjectResult) && methodType.IsGenericType)
       {
        var test = j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType.GetGenericArguments();
        if (test.Length > 0)
        {
         myMethods.Add(j);
         System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(j.ReturnType.UnderlyingSystemType.GetGenericArguments()[0].ToString());
        }
       }`

Sorry, not sure why it's not formatting my code in this comment.

Comment: Updated syntax in my answer.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks for the help. Do you have any recommended reading material for learning more about these generic proxy objects?

Comment: There is not too much to read about. This is just an another layer what EF adds so that all the procedures return single object type. This allows EF to implement some additional logic between procedure call occures and result is fetched. You can lookup specific class in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739113(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm actually having a problem with the 
`methodType == typeof(ObjectResult)`
. (It's returning false for everything.)

Comment: I removed 
`methodType == typeof(ObjectResult)` and used only the
`methodType.IsGenericType` and it passed my unit tests.